# Detect when Gamekit receives data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sms, gamekit

I am building a chat app and now working on the bubble interface.  I have the code to draw the bubbles and everything is ready except for one thing. I need to detect whether a message has been received or if its been sent. I have the following code except I don't know what to fill in place of the MESSAGE WAS RECEIVED.

```
if(MESSAGE WAS RECEIEVED)
{
    balloonView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0, size.width + 28, size.height + 15);
    balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(16, 8, size.width + 5, size.height);
}
else
{

    balloonView.frame = CGRectMake(320.0f - (size.width + 28.0f), 2.0f, size.width + 28.0f, size.height + 15.0f);
    balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(307.0f - (size.width + 5.0f), 8.0f, size.width + 5.0f, size.height);
}
```

This is inside the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thanks,
AD

Comment: What have you tried for "MESSAGE WAS RECEIVED"? GameKit is well [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/WorkingwithSessions/WorkingwithSessions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH101-SW1) so you should find enough info to get started.

Comment: i haven't tried anything, i have absolutely no idea what to put there. I looked through the documentation but I can't find any mention of what i need.